# What is the intention behind asking weight of plane?

Tags: interview

I was asked this question "How would you find weight of Aeroplane" in an interview and I am not sure why this question was one of the two question asked in the interview.

I tried to answer it using all possible ways but could not give the correct answer.(found the correct answer after google search)

How much such questions decide your selection in the interview?

Here was my approach:
1. If measurement of plane is given then i will calculate volume and multiply by density, will consider fuel weight plus other dead weight.
2. Using water displacement method if i can put plane in water and somehow measure how much water is displaced.

But found using google search that right approach was to put place on a ship and mark the level of water on the hull, then remove plane and then ship will go up.
And start putting weight on the ship till marked hull reaches the water level.

Comment: What was the question. It was probably to see how you approach the problem.

Comment: Question was "How would you find the weight of aeroplane?"

Comment: This really isn't a good question (as in yours) but I'm guessing they asked you this question to see if you could come up with an approach. I doubt they just said "What is the weight of any airplane you can think of" unless they wanted you to ask questions about the airplane.

Comment: Did you ask, "Are there any fat people aboard?"

Comment: And since we are here...what is an airplane. Its a cylinder with a few triangles and a cone or two. Stuff inside it. If you knew density of the materials making of the skin, framing, how much fuel, how many seats you could tease out enough info to have satisfied their question.

Comment: Just call the manufacturer of said aeroplane and ask them how much it weighs.

Comment: @Thomas : Yes, I asked if plane is flying or stationary, then if plane has passangers or not, then I asked if measurement is available or not, then gave measurement approach, then provided water displacement approach. I even asked if the plane is real plane or a toy plane, and he said what if it is a toy plane? I told him if it is a toy plane then i will simply use weight machine, then he told ok, its not toy plane. ;)

Comment: @Rig, You are right, I told him this approach, but he wanted to hear the answer which he had in his mind, so he kept saying, "What Else..What else" :)

Comment: "I must be in the wrong room. I thought I was interviewing for a *programming* job at *not-Boeing* ... Well this is super awkward ... Bye."

Comment: @ThomasEding: Many many fat people, and what kind of plane? A 747 with two fat people is not the same as an ultralight with two fat people... ;)

Comment: Anytime someone asks you the weight of a plane, it's pretty obvious what the intent is. This person intends to lift a plane, high-ball the estimate because you really don't want them trying, they could hurt themselves and sue you.

Comment: Putting weight back on the ship is tedious beyond believe. Any ship has information available on exactly how much volume is displaced at all levels that it can (safely) "sink" (sic) to. So when you have the levels with/without plane, just measure the water densitiy (varies with salinity) and do a little math with the displacement information. But I admit that I have prior knowledge, being trained as a ship's nautical officer... :-D

Comment: [Aircraft Scales](http://www.aircraftscales.com/). Problem solved.

Comment: To follow up on what *Mike* said, the FAA has very specific rules for how to measure the weight of a plane, [and they don't involve boats](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/media/FAA-H-8083-1A.pdf) (and speaking as a former private pilot, if asked this question I would reply with "the current weight and balance sheet is required to be in the cockpit, so let's go take a look").

Comment: I was on an aerospace degree before I became a programmer; I'd LOVE to get this question. I wonder how far into the constraints calculation they'd let me get...

Comment: I feel like you should be able to somehow measure the tyre pressure before and after landing to calculate this.

Comment: I work with aeronautical software systems where Maximum Take Off Weight (MTOW) is a critical piece of information. I'm yet to weigh one, personally. Usually a call to the manufacturer would suffice...

Comment: I find the answer "oh, I was googling this earlier, what a coincidence. Well, the answer is 2.3 tonnes. Next question please!" screws the interviewer's composure quite a lot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Job Interview 2.0: Now With Riddles!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Riddle-Me-An-Interview.aspx) would be an article from TheDailyWTF that notes some of these including the weight of a 747, which is a type of plane:

> Thankfully, Microsoft realized that the type of people who enjoy these
>   riddles aren’t always good programmers, and good programmers aren’t
>   always the type who enjoy these riddles. In fact, some of the folks
>   who can solve these riddles are precisely the type of people you don’t
>   want as programmers. Would you want to work with the guy who builds a
>   water-displacement scale/barge, taxis a 747 to the docks, and then
>   weights the jumbo jet using that, instead of simply calling Boeing in
>   the first place?
>
> Unfortunately, Microsoft’s realization came too late: a whole
>   mini-industry has spawned around the concept of Job Interview 2.0. If
>   Microsoft did it, it must work, right? There are books written on
>   brainteasers in the interview, consultants who will help your company
>   annoy the hell out candidates with your very own custom brainteasers,
>   and now, everyone from small software firms to big ole’ banks are
>   asking stupid riddle questions.

The key point in these questions is that it isn't so much that there is a correct answer as much as it is how well can you communicate how you'd solve this problem and upon revisions to the problem, what alternative approaches would you take.  For the weight of a plane, I'd probably look at specifications which should note this as part of the basics about the plane.  Failing that, then there are a few other approaches one can take.

Answer (score 5):

Reminds me of the Niels Bohr "measure the hieght of a building using a barometer" [story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question)

The purpose of these questions is twofold.

1. Is to see how you logically go about solving a problem (dos not matter if you don't come up with an answer as long as you demonstrate some reasonable thought process).
2. Is to see how you react under pressure. An unexpected question in a job interview is very stressful, will you prevaricate gracefully until you come up with an answer or break into a cold sweat and lose the power of speech.

Personally I would like to have answered ( but as it took me 10 minutes to think this up I probably would not have -- I am more of a cold sweat and silence kind of a guy :-) )

Count the number of wheels. Measure the air pressure of one of the wheels before and after takeoff ( after tires cool down) and calculate the difference in pressure.

```
 footprint of tire in inches * pressure difference in psi * number of wheels 
      = weight in pounds.
```

Simple, unobtrusive and very approximate.

Comment: I should also add that these interview questions are extremely biased towards applicants that have foreknowledge that the riddle will be asked. I.E. anyone who has an acquaintance who has been through the process, or, anyone applying through a recruitment agency which has prior experience of the company.

Comment: The classic barometer answer is "_I would go down to the basement, and tell the superintendent, 'I will give you this lovely barometer if you will tell me the height of this building.'_"

Comment: Shouldn't the "pressure difference in psi" term just be "pressure when parked"?

Comment: "But on no account should you try to estimate the height of the building by measuring the difference in air pressure -- the results would be hopelessly inaccurate"

Comment: @recursive -- that would assume 0 PSI when the plane took off. Normally these things are pumped up :-).

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, this is one of the riddles described in the book ["How Would You Move Mount Fuji?: Microsoft's Cult of the Puzzle -- How the World's Smartest Companies Select the Most Creative Thinkers"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316778494)

[image]

The basic idea of these kind of question is to see the way people think about the problem, how do they analyse it, how do they solve it. The "correct" answer isn't always relevant. Microsoft idea was that thanks to such a interview questions, they could select inexperienced but very smart people, and train them to be great developers, rather than directly look for good experienced developers. While the concept might have been good idea in 1980s, it's been long phased out by Microsoft and other big tech companies. Still, the myth that *"this is how MS/Google/FB hires best people"* lingers on.

Comment: I always thought that riddles are simply a proxy to measure intelligence short of an IQ test. The problem is that "intelligence", whatever it is, is not a scalar. If someone needs a good athlete, the first question that comes to mind is what kind of athlete you need (a swimmer, long distance runner, etc). These tests only measure logic, not memory or any other mental skill. The second problem is how "intelligence" correlates with the programmer profitability. It's intuitive that there is some correlation, but apparently time has shown it is a weak one.

Answer (score 1):

The 'intention' is to judge what kind of problem solver you are.

But... Google recently let it be known that such questions are a huge waste of time that serve no purpose other than making the interviewer feel smart.  They actually crunched the numbers and found no correlation between how a candidate did on the questions and how successful they were at their jobs.  It turns out that the most effective way to judge a candidate is by asking them about their experience and then following up with questions.  (Which so happens to be the approach this brilliant individual has been promoting for years: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14666/897)

So to answer your other question about how much this sort of thing impacts your chances of being hired... at Google (or any other company with a shred of common sense), zero impact.  Unfortnately, much of the world is comprised of sheep who just follow the leader, and there are undoubtably a lot of companies that are still using these kinds of questions because they read in some 10 year magazine article that Google and Microsoft do it.

(source found through google news, but there's tons of other articles about it)
http://venturebeat.com/2013/06/20/google-says-tricky-job-interview-brainteasers-were-a-waste-of-time/

Answer (score 1):

I am roughly in agreement with the assertions that this is a 'brainteaser' intended to see how you think.  However, this is a real world problem, and it isn't trivial. The Air Force has 'Load Masters' whose only job is to figure out whether a given cargo manifest will fly, and if so how to balance and secure it.

So you start with the 'empty weight' of the plane, which (as is pointed out above) you get from the flight manual AKA the manufacturer.  It isn't quite this simple, because commercial aircraft in particular have different seating and accessory configurations, and these affect total weight.  Therefore, strictly speaking, you have to know the weight of the individual aircraft, not the model. This stuff is in the aircraft cockpit, and if you're asked to write code for it it's the employer's responsibility to provide you with the data.

Then you add weight of freight, weight of passengers, and weight of fuel.  Freight is fairly routine, however weight of passengers gets interesting, because there can be major differences, and normally airlines don't ask. A flight to Orlando with a bunch of kids is different from flights in and out of New Orleans, which tend to be adults indulging in culinary hedonism.

The fuel issue is then figured from the empty weight + freight + passengers (times miles + alternate + 45 minute reserve). Fuel needed depends on expected operating altitude and to a lesser extent the temperature and humidity of the departure airport - less dense air means longer takeoff runs.

If you had been able to get this far you would have probably overrun the interviewer, unless they're a pilot or unless the company you were going to work for is an airline.  A lot of the time the 'long way around' solutions are exactly what frighten the interviewer. They would rather you just look up the starting numbers and then start computing the end result from the respective variables.

Of course, I could have just led you down the wrong track - this is what I would have said, but if all they wanted to know was the empty weight then your formula would have to have been based on the (length * diameter of the fuselage * thickness of the skin * weight of the material) + (wing area * average thickness of the wing * weight of material) + (rough volume of engine * density of the materials in the engine * number of engines).  It sounds like they gave you more than one chance.  Next time someone asks you'll know.